# Keep the first value using pandas diff()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, diff

I got a dataframe as shown below:

```
Note: Datetime is the index
           Name   target_mtd
Datetime 
2021-12-01 Amy     1000
2021-12-02 Amy     2500
2021-12-03 Amy     4000
2021-12-01 Bobo    2000
2021-12-02 Bobo    3000
2021-12-03 Bobo    4000
```

And I would like to transform the column `target_mtd` into daily values in each group, therefore I perform the following code:

```
df['target_daily'] = df.groupby([df.index.month, 'Name'])['target_mtd'].transform(lambda x:x.diff())
```

And gives the result which is not the same as I expected:

```
           Name   target_mtd  target_daily
Datetime 
2021-12-01 Amy     1000         NaN
2021-12-02 Amy     2500         1500
2021-12-03 Amy     4000         1500
2021-12-01 Bobo    2000         NaN
2021-12-02 Bobo    3000         1000
2021-12-03 Bobo    4000         1000
```

Expected result is that the first value will be kept:

```
           Name   target_mtd  target_daily
Datetime 
2021-12-01 Amy     1000         1000
2021-12-02 Amy     2500         1500
2021-12-03 Amy     4000         1500
2021-12-01 Bobo    2000         2000
2021-12-02 Bobo    3000         1000
2021-12-03 Bobo    4000         1000
```

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby([df.index.month, 'Name'])['target_mtd'].transform(np.diff, prepend=0)` with `numpy`'s `np.diff` you can use the parameter `prepend`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace missing values by original column by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['target_daily'] = (df.groupby([df.index.month, 'Name'])['target_mtd']
                        .diff()
                        .fillna(df['target_mtd']))
```

If there is multiple years is necessary use month periods for distinguish years with months separately:

```
df['target_daily'] = (df.groupby([df.index.to_period('m'), 'Name'])['target_mtd']
                        .diff()
                        .fillna(df['target_mtd']))
```

Or use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) per months (also years + months are count separately):

```
df['target_daily'] = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='m'), 'Name'])['target_mtd']
                        .diff()
                        .fillna(df['target_mtd']))
```